# Сделать нормальный выход из чата с++

Tags: c++, winsock, чат, сетевое-программирование

Когда один из клиентов чата закрывает чат (закрывает приложение), на сервере начинает лагать его последнее сообщение (отправляться много раз), то бишь не происходит выход из while() (строка 74)

Вот сервер:

```
#include < iostream >
#pragma comment( lib, "ws2_32.lib" )
#include < Windows.h >
#include < conio.h >
using namespace std;

#define HELLO   "Welcome to our chat"
#define MY_PORT    666

char buff[1024];
int nclients = 0;


DWORD WINAPI WorkWithClient(LPVOID client_socket);

int main() {
//серверный сокет
SOCKET mysocket;
sockaddr_in local_addr;

if (WSAStartup(0x0202, (WSADATA *)&buff[0])) { printf("Error WSAStartup 
%d\n", WSAGetLastError()); }

if ((mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0) { printf("Error socket 
%d\n", WSAGetLastError()); WSACleanup(); }

local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
local_addr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;

if (bind(mysocket, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr))) {

    printf("Error bind %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(mysocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

if (listen(mysocket, 20)) {

    printf("Error listen %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(mysocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

//Клиентский сокет
SOCKET client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in clinfo;
/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////
printf("Waiting for connection\n");
while (client_socket = accept(mysocket,NULL,NULL))
{
    nclients++;

    // вывод сведений о клиенте
    cout << "New connection: " << endl;

    DWORD thID;
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, WorkWithClient,&client_socket, NULL, &thID);


}
printf("Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
cin.get();
return 0;
}



DWORD WINAPI WorkWithClient(LPVOID client_socket) {

char nick[128];
int bytes_recv;
SOCKET my_sock;
my_sock = ((SOCKET *)client_socket)[0];
send(my_sock, HELLO, sizeof(HELLO), 0);




while (1)
{
    bytes_recv = recv(my_sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    send(my_sock, &buff[0], bytes_recv, 0);

    if (!strcmp(&buff[0], "quit\n")) {
        break;
    } else if (!strcmp(&buff[0], "list\n")) {

    } else { cout << buff << std::endl; }

}

nclients--;
printf("%d: disconnected", nick);
closesocket(my_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет проверки на ошибки чтения и записи... Добавьте после вызова `bytes_recv = recv(my_sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);` проверку вида:

```
if(bytes_recv == SOCKET_ERROR){
    //клиент отключился 
    break;
}
```

p.s. лучше не игнорируйте то, что вам возвращают `send` и `recv`, а всегда проверяйте, ну и RTFM естественно. [Примеры](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/basics/) по Winsock